# Android Toolbar becomes translucent when navigating back

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

**Example Project Illustrating Issue**

https://github.com/justincpollard/TransparentToolbarExample

**Background**

We have an `Activity`/`Fragment` combination used to display content in our app. Our users are able to navigate between pieces of content, which essentially lays these `Activity`/`Fragment` combos one on top of the other. Tapping either the hardware back button or the up button simply reveals the prior piece of content.

*The following references the example project*

When a user is viewing a piece of content, the Toolbar (`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`) and its text begin transparent. We accomplish that like so:

```
public void onCreateView(...) {
    ...
    toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ...
    actionBarDrawable = toolbar.getBackground();
    actionBarDrawable.setAlpha(0);
    actionBarText.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255));
    ...
}
```

If the user scrolls past a certain point on the page, e.g. scrolls an amount equal to the height of the Toolbar, we animate the alpha of the toolbar background & text from 0 to 255, essentially revealing the toolbar:

```
private void animateToolbar(final int start, final int finish) {
    toolbarIsAnimating = true;
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, finish);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
         toolbarAlpha = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
         actionBarDrawable.setAlpha(toolbarAlpha);
         actionBarText.setTextColor(Color.argb(toolbarAlpha, 255, 255, 255));
        if(toolbarAlpha == finish) {
          toolbarIsAnimating = false;
        }
       }
    });
    animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(300);
    animator.start();
}
```

**Problem**

When the user navigates from the original piece of content to another piece of content AFTER scrolling past the threshold point (i.e. the Toolbar background has been animated into view), pressing back/up reveal the original `Activity`/`Fragment` combo, but the Toolbar is completely transparent.

To illustrate in the example project, build and open the app, scroll to the bottom of the page, and press the "MORE CONTENT" button. Once you've navigated to the second `Activity`, press the back button. Notice that the Toolbar is transparent, though the title text is still visible.

Has anyone seen this problem before? I've only seen it on Android 5.+, but this will become more of a problem as adoption of 5.+ continues to grow.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm having the same issue too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny, @Gricher and I came across answers right around the same time. I haven't vetted his answer, but here's mine:

There's no need to deal with the `Drawable` returned from `toolbar.getBackground()`. You can accomplish the same thing by using a similar technique to what I've used to change the text color of the action bar.

Use this for the `animateToolbar()` method:

```
private void animateToolbar(final int start, final int finish) {
    toolbarIsAnimating = true;
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, finish);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
         toolbarAlpha = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
         toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(toolbarAlpha, 56, 204, 255));
         actionBarText.setTextColor(Color.argb(toolbarAlpha, 255, 255, 255));
        if(toolbarAlpha == finish) {
          toolbarIsAnimating = false;
        }
       }
    });
    animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(300);
    animator.start();
  }
```

The key is this:

`toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(toolbarAlpha, 56, 204, 255));`

Works on Android 6.+ (as it stands today) as well.

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution:

Instead of

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha();
```

You need to use

```
toolbar.getBackground().mutate().setAlpha();
```

Apparently drawables are by default sharing states among each other, calling mutate() will make this particular drawable not sharing state.